# Split a string according to First substring and 2nd another substring

Tags: php, html, curl

I have a HTML file code in a string that is like given below :

```
--- few lines of code ---------

<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var statList = new Array(
0, "192.168.1.179", "88-53-95-28-2B-AF", 194280, 101141053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, "192.168.1.170", "60-C5-47-10-37-FD", 132316, 65860791, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, "192.168.1.151", "68-5D-43-21-76-95", 9887, 3898646, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, "192.168.1.134", "6C-3E-6D-8C-FF-62", 26405, 7521875, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
4, "192.168.1.124", "04-F7-E4-78-D3-D0", 6189, 1791672, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
5, "192.168.1.121", "60-C5-47-10-40-92", 122657, 91113301, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
</SCRIPT>

---- Few other lines of code ---------
```

I want to extract the `<script>` block containing the `Array` declaration.

Can I do this with any PHP function?

Comment: Your first and second block seem identical to me?

Comment: I have written above that "few lines of code" above script code and below script code that I want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a clear delimiter that appears only once at the beginning of your string and another one that appears only once at the end, you can easily use preg_match. Otherwise, you can still use preg_match, but will have a much harder time writing a good RegExp. If you want to extract the IP/MAC data, you may want to start with a RegExp directly.

Answer (score 0):

What about this piece of code ?

```
$content = file_get_contents('____URL_of_your_html____');
if(preg_match('/(var statList = new Array\(.*?\);)/si',$content,$matches)){
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: You don't need any memory captures and you should use ungreedy matching. And you forgot the `/s` modifier.